# cakephp fixture import 100 records

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

In my cakephp 2.2.3 app I have a complicated model which has 3 belongsTo and 1 hasMany relation. I would like to test it by a unit test case.

Is there any way to import like 100 records from my existing database with all the related records? Or how to test a case like this?

In the existing database there is about 50,000 records and I do not want to import them all.

Comment: generating the fixture by ./Console/cake bake offers this as an option

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned using the `cake bake fixture` is the way to go for this, as the third question allows you to import items from your existing database.

[image]

Comment: What field in the array variable $import of the fixture is that?

Comment: Sorry @Karol I don't understand your question.

Comment: What I mean is: I'd like to do the importing from a file (like my_fixture.php in app/test/fixtures). I know I can specify the $import variable and set records=true in it, but I don't know how to limit the number of imported records there.

Comment: Id' suggest baking a file and seeing what's in it!

Comment: The baked file contains records, I think. Anyway, I wrote my own simple importer in about 15 minutes. Thanks for the response.